# setOnClickListner() is not working a nested recyclerView android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I create a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) containing list of items with vertical orientation.
I added another RecyclerView inside a single node in the parent RecyclerView to show a grid of items inside each cell.
I added a click listener for the grid item in the cell as like : `mRvHomeMosaic.setOnClickListener(this);` inside view holder, but it's not getting triggered by a click.
Please help me, if anyone has the same problem. Or anyone who use Nested RecyclerView.

My Holder class and onBindView() is given below

```
class HomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        RecyclerView mRvHomeMosaic;
        public HomeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);  
            this.mRvHomeMosaic = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_home_mosaic_image);      
            mRvHomeMosaic.setEnabled(true);
            mRvHomeMosaic.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.itemClickListner(view, getPosition());
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final HomeViewHolder holder, int position) {                 
             if (mDataList.get(position).getmMosaicModelList() != null &&
                     mDataList.get(position).getmMosaicModelList().size() > 0) {
                 holder.mRvHomeMosaic.setEnabled(true);
                 HomeSubAdapter adapter = new HomeSubAdapter(mContext, mDataList.get(position).
                         getmMosaicModelList());
                 holder.mRvHomeMosaic.setAdapter(adapter);
                 StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,
                         StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                 holder.mRvHomeMosaic.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
             } else {
                 holder.mRvHomeMosaic.setEnabled(true);
                 List<MosaicTileModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
                 MosaicTileAdapter adapter = new MosaicTileAdapter(mContext, modelList);
                 holder.mRvHomeMosaic.setAdapter(adapter);
                 StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,
                         StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                 holder.mRvHomeMosaic.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
             }
    }`
```

The single node has some other items also. Click listener is properly triggered that items. But in the case of Inner Recylcerview object it's not getting triggered.

Comment: just add a tag to the object and extract object in click listener from that tag.

Comment: try to not pass `this` to `mRvHomeMosaic.setOnClickListener()` and use `new View.setOnClickListener()` as an argument.

Comment: The onClickListner() is properly working for other items in each cell. The only problem is for inner recyclerview object (in My case mRvHomeMosaic). I need to get the click for that  recyclerView (In my case mRvHomeMosaic). Is I need to do something for that?